# Index Match Large multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help please.

```
=INDEX(Data!$L:$L,MATCH(1,INDEX((Data!$O:$O=LARGE(Data!$O:$O,ROWS(Calcs!F$1:F3)))*(COUNTIF(Calcs!F$1:F3,Data!$O:$O)=0),),0))
```

I have this formula to look through data and pull the top 5 site numbers (SIN) starting with the largest amount of hours.

What I need the formula to do is to search by branch number so that when I select a branch (branch number is updated in cell `A1` of "Calcs Tab") it will look in the data table and pull the Site number (SIN) for the largest 5 sites (most hours) by branch (that's in cell `A1`).

My data tab is below:

[image: Data Tab]

This formula is in cell `F2` on the "Calcs Tab" and I drag it down to get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc (Highest Hours).

As requested, this is the data:

[image: Data Tab 2]

Please help, sorry if this is not very clear. My first ever post!

Thank You

[image: Daat Tab 3]

Comment: Better edit your post and attach the real Screen Shot so that we may understand the Data structure properly to fix the issue!!

Comment: @Sinead It appears that you may have accidentally created two accounts ([here](https://superuser.com/users/1002896/sinead) and [here](https://superuser.com/users/1002900/sinead)) which may be why you couldn't edit your question. You may wish to have a look at the Help Center article [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on fixing this issue.

Comment: Thank you @Anaksunaman. I have now merged my accounts

Comment: @RajeshS I have updated it, hope it is more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Data:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

**How it works:**

- Fill `1` to `5` from **C22** to **C26** 
  to set Order to get `Largest Hours` in 
  adjacent Column.
- Fill *Branch No* in **B22**.
- Formula in **A22**:

  `=IF(B22=6,"Bristol",IF(B22=10,"Glassgow",IF(B22=2,"London",IF(B22=9,"Liverpool",IF(B22=8,"Barmingham","")))))`
- Array (CSE) Formula in **D22**, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  `{=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(($A$2:$A$19=$B$22)*($B$2:$B$19=$A$22)*($E$2:$E$19),C22))}`

*Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in **E22**, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$19,MATCH(1,($A$22=$B$2:$B$19)*($B$22=$A$2:$A$19)*(D22=$E$2:$E$19),0)),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- *As soon you change `Branch No` in 
  **B22**, you get `SIN` in **E22** 
  downwards.*
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.*
- For easy identification I've applied `Red 
  & Green` colors to `Branch No 6` and 
  `10`.